# is possible run selenium with headless browser to handle functionalities?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, headless-browser

My objective is running automation based selenium webdriver from Jenkins, but jenkins cannot open browser when build job. so I modified my code to run in headless mode. since implementing headless browser, having some big question

- is possible to handle end to end business on headless browser? cause end to end need inspect element as the process
- if headless browser cannot handle, do you have some suggestion?

thanks, I'm very low to integrate automation

Comment: Headless is not exactly like normal chrome, few things like download files, add extension, are not yet allowed. So it may or may not work depending on tests you are executing

Comment: so headless just handle small part of automation ? @TarunLalwani

Comment: Again based on your requirement, there are test suites which completely run on Headless, its just what all your test suites need, even few websites for some reason don't work fine in headless, so you have try and see if it works for you

Comment: Instead of trying to run with headless mode. you can find the cause for not opening browser when building the job.

Comment: i thought jenkins not able to open browser so our test could be fail. i tried it before. so i just need many suggestion to make the continues integration that handle end to end functionalities @Murthi

Comment: older version of jenkins was running in background on windows. I am not sure about newer version. please check you scripts are running in background mode.

Comment: found the solution, i must install jenkins use jenkins.war and build project as maven with insert custom workspace. last time install use jenkings.pkg. thx a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the code to run a Selenium test with Jenkins in headless mode.

You can use a [Jenkins plugin of a headless X server](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin) to run your tests on an installed browser. You will even get screenshots.

Comment: i dont need to remove firefox driver ?

Comment: No. With that setup firefox sends its graphical output to an X server which is headless on Jenkins. Locally you can run the same code with graphical output.