# How to execute jenkins jobs in non-headless mode?

Tags: jenkins, google-chrome-headless

AutoIT is not working in headless mode while using via jenkins.

I have tried as per below link, but doesnot help.
[How to run my automation(test) on Jenkins without using the Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595677/how-to-run-my-automationtest-on-jenkins-without-using-the-headless)

Is there any setting to disable headless mode in jenkins? Or can we execute some cases in headless mode and some in non-headless mode?